# Is $\mathbb{Q} ({\sqrt[3] 2})$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q} (\omega{\sqrt[3] 2})?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

> Is $\mathbb{Q} ({\sqrt[3] 2})$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q} (\omega{\sqrt[3] 2})$, where $\omega =e^{2\pi i/3}$?

My attempt :  I found the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2914419/how-to-prove-that-mathbbq-sqrt32-is-isomorphic-to-mathbbqe2-pi/2914435?noredirect=1#comment8655764_2914435).  But  i think this answer is wrong.

Here

$\mathbb{Q} ({\sqrt[3] 2})=\{a + b\sqrt[3] 2 +c(\sqrt[3] 2)^2 |a,b,c \in \mathbb{Q} \}$

$\mathbb{Q} (\omega{\sqrt[3] 2})=\{a + b(\omega\sqrt[3] 2) +c(\omega\sqrt[3] 2)^2 |a,b,c \in \mathbb{Q} \}$

Suppose  $f:\mathbb{Q} ({\sqrt[3] 2})\to\mathbb{Q} (\omega{\sqrt[3] 2})$ is  an isormorphism  then

$f ({\sqrt[3] 2})=a + b\omega\sqrt[3] 2 +c(\omega\sqrt[3] 2)^2\implies  f(2)=(a + b\omega\sqrt[3] 2 +c(\omega\sqrt[3] 2)^2)^3$  but $f(2)= 2 f(1)=2$

$\implies2\neq(a + b\omega\sqrt[3] 2 +c(\omega\sqrt[3] 2)^2)^3$ .
So our assumption is a  Contradiction

Therefore $\mathbb{Q} ({\sqrt[3] 2})$  is not  isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q} (\omega{\sqrt[3] 2})$.

Comment: This should say $\omega = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}$, not $\omega = e^{\frac{2\pi}{3}}$, yes?

Comment: @Luna145 i edited

Comment: $2 = (a + b\omega\sqrt[3] 2 +c(\omega\sqrt[3] 2)^2)^3$ with $a=c=0$ and $b=1$.

Comment: I'm afraid you seem to be out of your depth with this approach. The same argument would "prove" that $\Bbb{Q}(\root3\of2)$ is not isomorphic with itself, which is absurd.

Comment: Just try $f(a+b\root3\of2+c\root4\of4)=a+b\omega\root3\of2+c\omega^2\root3\of4$. I think you need to spend more time understanding what an isomorphism is. You have not understood this question unless it is clear to you why my suggested $f$ is implied by azif00's comment.

Comment: Exactly sir @JyrkiLahtonen Actually ,I'm new to the field theory.

Comment: Both these fields are isomorphic to $\mathbb {Q} [x] /(x^3-2)$ and hence isomorphic to each other.

Comment: You were new to fields [two and a half years ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2983851/11619). I am worried about the lack of progress. I recommend that you talk long and hard with your teacher. Are you studying on your own?

Comment: yes sir @JyrkiLahtonen  I study by myself.Actually  , im a  slow learner